# jQuery FullCalendar: Change allDay criteria to check for string instead of bool

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm building an app that gets a JSON feed and uses that to populate a jQuery FullCalendar calendar.

The problem is that one of the criteria is "allDay" which can be true / 1 or false / 0, and my JSON feed is returning "true" / "1" or "false" / "0" - ie - strings

As it stands I can't change the JSON feed, so does anyone know how I can modify the fullcalendar.js script to check for a string instead?

Comment: Could you show us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
        event.allDay = true;
    } else {
        event.allDay = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Was looking for a way to do this, saved me a ton of time.